# Example of an $H^{-1}$ function that isn't $L^2$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I'm going back over some PDE and Sobolev space theory, and the following is puzzling to me.  Consider a nice domain $\Omega$ and the space $H^1_0(\Omega)$ of functions with $L^2$ first derivatives, vanishing at the boundary in the trace sense.  Evans (section 5.9, page 299) then defines the dual of $H_0^1$, $H^{-1}$.  He then makes sure to emphasize that we cannot identify $H_0^1$ with its dual.  Why not?  Isn't $H_0^1$ a Hilbert space?  Is there an example of a distribution $f\in H^{-1}$ such that $f\notin L^2$, for instance?

Edit: in 1 dimension, we know that $u\in H^1_0$ has a continuous "version", so that for instance I think the Dirac delta distribution must be in $H^{-1}$.  What about higher dimensions, where $H^1_0$ functions are not guaranteed to be continuous?

Comment: You *can* associate them *as Hilbert spaces*. In doing so, however, you strip all of the other analytic structure since the Riesz representation theorem doesn't see the "finer" details of a Hilbert space. So if you associate them, you're really ignoring all of the analytic structure underneath which is why you don't want to identify them. It's not too dissimilar from the idea that any two infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces are isometrically isomorphic. You can associate them but different representations of the same Hilbert space can carry different structures and do different things for you.

Comment: Got it...I guess I've been getting too cozy with $L^2$!  Thanks.

Comment: For instance, you can abstractly look at $L^2(\Bbb R)$ and the Fourier transform operator and in doing so (if you pick your basis right), the Fourier transform is diagonal with complex entries of $\pm 1,\pm i$. However once you've abstracted, you've really lost the true meaning of the Fourier transform. There are merits and pitfalls to abstractly looking at spaces. You can easily identify some of the fundamental properties by abstracting but you can also lose/cover-up structure by viewing things at too high of a bird's eye view. This is something to keep in mind in analysis.

Comment: Incidentally, examples of distributions $f\in H^{-1}\backslash L^2$ can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289029/example-of-function-u-in-h-1-omega-setminus-l2-omega?rq=1).  Not sure how I didn't see that question before.

Comment: Those are some pretty good examples. Nice catch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can identify $H^1_0$ with $H^{-1}$ by Riesz Representation Theorem, because $H^1_0$ is Hilbert space. But, in this case, is not a "good" idea to do this identification.

You can consult [Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Diferential Equations, by Brezis](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387709130), in the page 136, he makes a comment about it, and you will understand that choice of *"not identify $H^1_0$ with $H^{-1}$"* in Theorem of Characterization of $H^{-1}.$

Comment: Thanks for the reference.  I even had that book open next to me, I was just looking in the wrong chapter.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 4):

For example, for $\Omega=\mathbb{R}$, the distribution $\delta_0$ defined by $\delta_0(\varphi)=\varphi(0)$ belongs to $H^{-1}(R)$(in fact $\delta\in H^s(R)$ for $s<-1/2$) but don't belong to $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.