# Representation of the delta distribution as an element of the dual of $H^1$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

I'm working with some Sobolev spaces and I just wanted to consider the elements of $H^{-1}$ as elements on $H^1$ (Riez Theorem). Since the delta function $\delta(f) = f(0)$ is an element of the dual of $H^1$, who is his representative?

i.e. I want some $g \in H^1$ such that$$ \int g h dx + \int g' h' dx = h(0) \quad \forall h \in H^1$$

Comment: I asked a very similar question a while back - see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1337967/example-of-an-h-1-function-that-isnt-l2).

Comment: You should also bear in mind that this only holds in dimension one.

Comment: Look at this problem posted just before yours. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1772994/show-that-there-exists-a-unique-v-0-in-h10-1-such-that-u0-int-01uv